# Sequelize Push WHERE Clause to Array

Tags: sequelize.js

In version 3 of sequelize I used to push objects to the where clause array like so:

```
where.push({[property]: {['Op.' + oper]: value}})
```

When I do this in version 5 of sequelize it no longer work. It seems to convert ['Op.' + oper] to a string that looks something like this 'Op.like'.

The goal is for the WHERE clause to look like the following:

```
WHERE (name LIKE '%mark%) AND (title = 'MANAGER') AND ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Op.and` and make its value as an array because in your case you really want to use exactly AND operator:

```js
const where = {
  [Op.and]: []
}
where[Op.and].push({[property]: {['Op.' + oper]: value}})
```

Comment: So this got me close. I had to do it like this:  

where[Op.and].push({[property]: {[Op.like]: value}})

Comment: I just showed an example of the whole idea